# Export functions individually in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Sorry if it's a duplicate but I can't find the solution to this issue.

In NodeJS, I need to export functions from one file to another. Here is what I tried in order to export (written in typescript):

```
/*** db.ts ***/

module.exports = {
    getDoc: (id:string):any =>  {
        return new Observable((observer:any) => {
            //Do something
        });
    },
    addDoc: (document:any):any =>  {
        return new Observable((observer:any) => {
            //Do something
        });
    },
}
```

And to import:

```
/*** main.ts ***/

import { getDoc, addDoc } from './db'
```

I want to keep this structure (being able to call each function - `getDoc` and `addDoc` - separately).

What am I doing wrong? The export doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is value of 'module' in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonJS exports aren't type-safe.

If they are used as named imports:

```
import { getDoc, addDoc } from './db'
```

They should be named exports as well:

```
export const getDoc = (id:string):any =>  {
    return new Observable((observer:any) => {
        //Do something
    });
};

export const addDoc = (document:any):any =>  {
    return new Observable((observer:any) => {
        //Do something
    });
};
```

Both `export` and `import` are supposed to be transpiled to CommonJS modules by TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
module.exports = {
    firstMethod: function() {},
    secondMethod: function() {}
}
```

For calling your methods

```
var Methods = require('./db.js');
var method = Methods.firstMethod;
```